# Can I use a web crawler to add new youtube videos to a playlist?

Tags: javascript, youtube, web-crawler

I'm new to coding, like real new, like "just started taking Javascript lessons on Code academy" new.

So here's what I want to do:
Some of the You Tube channels I'm  subscribed to, I'll use IGN for an example, upload multiple videos a day. I would like to program a web crawler to go on to IGN's You Tube page at 11:00 pm every night and add every video that has been uploaded in the past 24 hours to a new playlist and then name that Playlist with that days date. For example: "IGN News 3.18.16"

Is this somthing that can be done with a web crawler using Javascript and if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: That's what [APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) are for.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely! Let's break your problem down:

1. Need to schedule some code that gets run at certain time every day
2. This code needs to ask YouTube (via HTTP) for a playlist
3. This code needs to save this information locally

Ok, so let's get some information for each of these tasks:

1. We can schedule code to execute at an arbitrary time by using Scheduled Tasks (Windows) or cron jobs (Linux). Because you want to use JavaScript, a good Google phrase is "node javascript scheduled job"
2. We have two options here: we can either send a GET request to an HTML page and then parse the contents (a bit more complicated) OR we can use an API if one is provided by YouTube. From @Prinzhorn's comment, it looks like there is an API we can use. You will need to consider the following when using an API (the API's documentation will help answer these questions https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/):

   1. How do I authenticate with the API?
   2. What's the route (ie URL) of the information I want to get?
   3. Is there a wrapper for the language I want to use (JavaScript)? *Here a "wrapper" is simply a library that simplifies communicating with an API*
3. The simplest way to persist data is to write a text file. This is definitely possible with JavaScript and a good Google phrase would be "writing to file node javascript". If you start saving more and more data and want to optimize/speed up reading/writing of this data, it will be time to investigate using a database.

*Note: when I use the term "node" I'm referring to a tool that allows you to run JavaScript on a server/machine/your laptop outside of the browser. https://nodejs.org/en/*